# Is it possible that these modules conflict with each other?

Tags: views

I have a view set up with the format Views Accordion. I have installed the module draggable views so that I can order each node as I like whenever I add a new node to the view. I'm finding that the sort version of this view display isn't rendering the drag and drop anchors at all. Is it possible that there is a conflict between Views Accordion and Draggable Views?

Comment: It works perfectly using Views Accordion 7.x-1.0-rc2, Draggableviews 7.x-2.0 and Views 7.x-3.7. Follow the instructions for the 7.x-2x branch on the help page for DraggableViews: https://drupal.org/node/283498.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to clarify.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to use Draggable Views to reorder a View that uses the Views Accordion display format. However, as Jens mentioned, you can follow the instructions on the Draggable Views documentation page to clone the Views display and change its display format to *Table* or *HTML List*. This cloned display can then be used to order the items, and the order will be respected on the Views Accordion display (as long as it's part of the same View or uses Field API weights).